# Laravel 5.2 - Error with multiUpload images array

Tags: php, laravel, multi-upload

i'm creating a multiUpload images system in my form, i want that users can upload 4 images in 4 different inputs and save their image, but i have this error:

> NotReadableException in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\regalo\vendor\intervention\image\src\Intervention\Image\AbstractDecoder.php
>   line 302: Image source not readable

MY FORM

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'crea-regalo','method'=>'POST','class' => 'form-horizontal', 'files'=>true)) !!}

<!-- photo -->
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="textarea"> Picture </label>
   <div class="col-md-8">

    <div class="mb10">

     <input id="input-upload-img1" name="image[]" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text">
   </div>

   <div class="mb10">

     <input id="input-upload-img2" name="image[]" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text">
   </div>


   <div class="mb10">

     <input id="input-upload-img3" name="image[]" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text">
   </div>


   <div class="mb10">

     <input id="input-upload-img4" name="image[]" type="file" class="file" data-preview-file-type="text">
   </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

MY CONTROLLER

```
         foreach ($request->image as $imageArray){

            // get file
            $file = $request->file('image');
            // create istance - Maybe here start the problem, doesn't get the files images

            $image = image::make($imageArray);
            // create path
            $path = public_path().'/images/post/'.$get_post_created->id;
            // rename file 
            $name_file = $get_post_created->id . '.' . $imageArray->getClientOriginalExtension();

            // resize
            $image->resize(100,100);
            // save
            $image->save($path.$name_file);
            // store path reference
            $store_path = new ImageUpload();
            $store_path->path = 'images/post/'.$get_post_created->id.'/'.$name_file;
            $store_path->post_id = $get_post_created->id; 
            $store_path->save(); 
         }
```

I TRIED upload 2 images of 4 inputs:

```
public function creaPost(Request $request){
dd ($request->image); 
....
...
}
```

[image]

I don't know if the input name="image[]" array are getting fine the files, or maybe i have some problem in foreach cycle in my controller.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`$image = Image::make($file->getRealPath())` instead of your `$image = image::make($imageArray);`
Then you can do what you want with image and save it with your code `$image->save($path.$name_file);`